# android dialog box - setting opacity of background image

Tags: android

I have a dialog box which appears on top of a SurfaceView. I would like the dialog box to have a custom image as its background, but I would also like to make the image slightly transparent so you can see underneath.

Any ideas on how I can change the opacity of the image?

gameover.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/imagebackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

creation code from parent activity

```
    gameOverDialog = new Dialog(this);
    gameOverDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    gameOverDialog.setContentView(R.layout.gameover);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add alpha to the image when you create it (in photoshop...whatever). But you can also try getting the background image as a Drawable and calling setAlpha on it to get what you want. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setAlpha(int)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried setting up the background as a `Drawable` and it worked. I had to change this line of code though `gameOverDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.theme_transulcent` but this creates another problem, the dialog box goes full screen. Anyway, thank you for your answer.